# If the Sylow-$2$-subgroup of a group $G$ is cyclic then can it surject $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, semidirect-product

Suppose $G$ is a group such that Sylow-$2$-subgroup is cyclic. Then can it surject into $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$?

If $G$ is an abelian group and Sylow-2-subgroup is Cyclic, then it can not, by the Structure theorem of Abelian groups.

Is it true in general? Is it true in the case of $H\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$, when $|H|$ is odd.

Note that in case the Sylow-$2$-subgroup is cyclic and $|G|=2^km$ for some odd $m$, then $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $m$, say $H$. Since $(|H|,2^k)=1$, this implies that $G=H\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$.

Comment: In general, if a finite group $G$ surjects onto a $p$-group, then so does the restriction of of the surjection to any  Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly it is impossible in the case of $H\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$ for $|H|$ odd: if we restrict a homomorphism to $f:H \rtimes \Bbb Z_{2^k} \to \Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2$ to $H$, it will be trivial, hence $f$ is surjective iff its restriction to $\Bbb Z_{2^k}$ is surjective.

As you noted, an application of Schur-Zassenhaus shows that all possible finite groups with cyclic $2$-Sylow are of this form, so this answers the question.

Comment: Thank you so much